# What does it mean to have dual input range?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-electronics

Hi guys I am looking for a wide range input voltages DC-DC Converter as my inputs would vary from 12,24,36,42Vdc. I found this, the Murata NCS12 series which have an input ranges of 9-36V and 18-75V. Now what does that mean? Could it be I can input from 9-75V? Because it only has 1 pin for the input voltage.

Also what does the 10% load efficiency mean? Because I might need only 300mA but a peak of 1A for my application.

I might use the [NCS12S1205C](https://www.mouser.ph/datasheet/2/281/kdc_ncs12-255579.pdf).

So would this be great for my application of inputs 12,24,36,42V 300mA peak 1A ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> […] the Murata NCS12 series [has] input ranges of 9-36V and 18-75V. Now what does that mean?

Remember that this is describing a *series* of parts, which includes many different parts with different characteristics.

The parts with a nominal 12V input (order codes **NCS12**x**12**xxx) have an input range of 9-36V.

The parts with a nominal 48V input (order codes **NCS12**x**48**xxx) have an input range of 18-75V.

There is no single part that can accept voltages from both ranges.

---

> Also what does the 10% load efficiency mean?

I think you're confused. There is no such value in the datasheet.

The datasheet gives a range of efficiencies (e.g, 78-83.5% for the NCS12S1203C), and gives specific details on input currents under 10% and 100% load at specific input voltages, but there is no "10% load efficiency" specified. It's possible to calculate an efficiency at 10% load from the current values in the second table, though.

---

> So would this be great for my application of inputs 12,24,36,42V 300mA peak 1A ?

No. There is no part in this series which supports that range of input voltages.